# Separate function returning a list of widgets as a separate widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Imagine I have a function and I am calling this function in the children attribute of multiple other different widgets which expect children widgets for example a column or a row.

how can I avoid using a function to return the list of widgets? because it is not recommended in flutter.

This is my use case:

```
      List<Widget> _buildList() {
        return List.generate(actions!.length, (index) {
        // a lot of code
              ));
        });
      }
...
    Column(
    ....
    children: _buildList()
    );

 Row(
    ....
    children: _buildList()
    );
```

If I separate Column and Row as widget they will both have a lot of duplicate code because the List.generate is the same in both of them, so I to not duplicate I have to go back to making it a function again, so basically stuck in a loop. what can I do?

Comment: You can make the `Column` widget as a separate stateless widget with have your widget list and use it in your main code, that way your code will be `segregated` between different widgets/files

Comment: What are you trying to archive ?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: return a widget from customWidget will depend on where would you like to place it. It would be clear if you define what exactly *even a custom widget.*  means on your case.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I added my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter what type of widget you would like to return. In this example I am handling two type of widget. But A better practicing will be **creating separate itemBuilder that take data and return a widget**.

```dart
class MyCustomView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomView({
    super.key,
    required this.type,
  }) : assert(
          type == Row || type == Column,
          'type should a row, column',
        );

  final Type type;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = [.....yourWidgets];

    final Widget widget;
    if (type == Row) {
      widget = Row( children: children);
    } else {
      widget = Column( children: children);
    }

    return widget;
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
MyCustomView(type: Row),
MyCustomView(type: Column),
```